# White space around video html

Tags: html, css

So I have put a video on a blank page. The video size is 1366x768px but for some reason its a bit broken. The video is not centered if i put a footer on the page and there is a white space around it if there is no footer. I tried using `position:absolute;`, `left:0;` and `top:0;` but it didn't seemed to work.

HTML

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="videos/bgvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS

```
#myVideo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -10000;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 768px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

This is how it should be
[image]

This is what happens if i put a footer on the page
[image]

and this is what happens if there is no footer
[image]

Comment: try removing padding and margin from body and html, like: html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: Okay, so the centering when there is a footer on the page has been solved. I just have to wrap a div around it. While the space around the video, @jgdev it does not work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/sunny-parsana/pen/RwgjmWY

Answer (score 0):

Since your footer is a box model, it pushes the video to the top by its height + margin + padding + border. You should make your footer `position: absolute;` and adjust the position. That way it won't push the video up, but rather just hang above it

Answer (score 0):

In your html section, try adding this:

```
    html {   
      margin: 0;    
      padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Style section

```
    html, body, #page {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #header {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: green;
    }
```